# How to make Cmder start with root privileges in Windows 10

Tags: cmder

As, the title suggests, I don't know how to make Cmder starts as root. The script creator says that It is essential to run this script as root, otherwise airgeddon won't work properly. I hope someone can tell me how or even if it is possible to launch Cmder with root in Windows 10.

Comment: Very bad question. You should NOT run the whole terminal as root. Start only tab instead as Admin. https://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html#Create_new_console_dialog

Comment: Windows uses the "Run as Administrator" option. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: There is no `root` user in Windows - that's BSD/Linux only and while `System` and `NT Service\TrusteInstaller` share similar attributes with `root`, they're not alike and no direct correlation exists. The `Administrators` group allows _Run as Administrator_, which is similar to `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click 'cmder.exe' > Properties > Compatibility > Run as administrator
Make sure it's ticked then run cmder.exe